# DRF request is not defined for getting current user id

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

So What I've been trying to do is to have my API view only return objects that have their attributes `post_user` to the current id of the logged in user. These `post_user` attributes are populated as whenever I post it populates the variable with the current user's id through my serializer.

However, I am not successful as it says request is not defined. I just want to get the current user's id so that I can use it to filter my object returns

views.py

```
# To retrieve and list all posts with DRF
class ListPosts(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Posts.objects.get(post_user=request.user.id)
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

serializers.py

```
# serializer for posts to be taken
class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ('id','post_title','post_content',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        posts = Posts.objects.create(
            post_title=validated_data['post_title'],
            post_content=validated_data['post_content'],
            # gets the id of the current user
            post_user=self.context['request'].user.id, 
        )

        posts.save()
        return posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is in line

```
queryset = Posts.objects.get(post_user=request.user.id)
```

here request is not define at class declaration time. Solution is you can override the get_queryset method.

```
class ListPosts(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   queryset = Posts.objects.all()
   serializer_class = PostsSerializer
   permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

   def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
      return Posts.objects.filter(post_user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: This worked man! I had to make the return `Posts.objects.filter(post_user=self.request.user.id)` for my use tho

Answer (score 1):

Inherit `CreateModelMixin`'s features inside `PostsSerializer` and try to define your **create()** method like `def create(request, *args, **kwargs)`.

Finally, you can try to get user id using `request.user.id`.

For a better documentation, you can check https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/.

Also check what are Mixins and why do we use it (if you do not know).

For a little and brief definition, **Mixins are just class with methods that can be mostly inherited and used by our views**.

If you have any doubt, please comment.